# How to make a scrollable box without "fixed" height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive box within which new paragraphs will be added. I want the box to be able to scroll when it overflows in y direction instead of expanding. I don't want to set any exact height in px/em etc on the box. Is that possible without JavaScript / with JavaScript ?

Comment: without any height limit how you want to have a scroll? you will scroll what?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want the initial render (or rendering after browser height/width change) of the box to remain the same size even when new content may be added in the box -which would overflow in y direction.

Comment: all these details with some of code should belong to the question then

Comment: 1. render with desired text 2. determine element `offsetHeight` (or use jquery)  3. set height to current height

Comment: OP, your answer to @TemaniAfif sounds exactly like setting exact height

Comment: @YongQuan Lets say I have `height : 30%` I don't want the box to expand when new contents are dynamically added in it.

Comment: it won't expand if the height is set to 30% because 30% is fixed height as it 30% of the parent height

Comment: OP, post your existing code to help us understand your context

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you could make it without JS but here's an attempt with it.

```js
document.getElementById('box').style.height = document.getElementById('box').clientHeight + 'px';


function addPara() {
   var box = document.getElementById('box');
   
   box.innerHTML = box.innerHTML +  '<p>This is a very short example paragraph</p>';
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box">
  <h2>Box</h2>
</div>
<button onclick="addPara()">Add a Paragraph</button>
```

Js takes the height of the box and freezes it when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-height` if you want your container to be **flexible** but to become **scrollable** when it reaches a maximum size:

```css
.content{
   width:100%;
   max-height:80px;
   background-color:cyan;
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Small Bla<br>Bla
</div><br>

<div class="content">
  Overflow Bla (larger than max-height)<br> Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>
  Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>
</div>
```